# Why is the TIME 00:00:00 for bash process in ps command

Tags: command-line, bash, ps

While running the `ps` command, the output is as follows :

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
  494 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
29487 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
32617 pts/0    00:00:02 gedit
```

Why is the `TIME` `00:00:00` for `bash`?
According to [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ps-command-in-linux-with-examples/), the explanation is as follows :

> It is nothing but the total accumulated CPU utilization time for any process and 00:00:00 indicates no CPU time has been given by the kernel till now. In above example we found that, for bash no CPU time has been given.

Does someone has a better explanation ?

Comment: Because the ***CPU time*** spent by the `bash` process is less that a second. (Or less than half a second, in case that `ps` rounds to the nearest second.)

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Why is  CPU time spent by the `bash` process is less that a second? Can you please expand?

Comment: Because it does not do any number crunching stuff. `bash` simply reads commands from input and calls the relevant binary to do the job requested by the command. `bash` itself is not a CPU bound process. However you can make bash use some CPU by running the following bash command, waiting a few seconds and killing it using **Ctrl+C**: `while [[ true ]] ; do  : ; done`

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Can you post this as an answer, so that I could close the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ps` command reports the CPU usage of a process in *seconds*. If you want to get this information in *milliseconds*, you can look at the end of this answer.

`ps` truncates the total CPU time used by the process to the nearest low second, so you can safely assume that the process you looked up (`bash` in your case) had used **less than one CPU second** so far.

This is normal, because `bash` does not do any number crunching stuff to spend too many CPU cycles. `bash` simply reads commands from input and calls the relevant executable to do the job requested by the command.

`bash` itself is not a "CPU bound" process. However, you can make `bash` use some CPU time by running the following `bash` command, waiting a few seconds and killing it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>:

```
while [[ true ]] ; do : ; done
```

After that, you can check once more the CPU time spent by `bash` by running `ps` again.

---

I have written a simple script to display the total CPU time used by a process ***in milliseconds***. Actually, on most systems the clock ticks 100 times per second, so the accuracy of the output is *in tens of milliseconds*. You can call this script by passing a single parameter specifying the process ID of the process you are interested, e.g. it will be `494` in your question.

```
#!/bin/bash
usage="Usage: $(basename $0) pid"
case "$*" in
 ''|*[!0-9]*)
  echo "$usage" 1>&2
  exit 1
  ;;
 * )
  pid="$1"
  ;;
esac
read -r -a pinfo <<< $(cat "/proc/$pid/stat" 2>/dev/null)
if (( ${#pinfo[@]} == 0 )) ; then
  echo -e "No proccess with PID : $pid" >&2
  exit 2
fi
let clk_tck="$(getconf CLK_TCK)"
let utime="${pinfo[13]}"
let stime="${pinfo[14]}"
let cputime=(utime + stime)*1000/clk_tck
echo "PID : ${pinfo[0]}
Cmd : ${pinfo[1]}
CPU : $cputime msec"
```